# Best way to implement a swerve drive robot with Ros2 control

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ignition-fortress

I am implementing a swerve drive, also known as a 4 wheel independent steering and independent drive, robot. I am using ROS2 Humble with Gazebo Fortress on Ubuntu Jammy. To control the 4 steering angles (one for each wheel) and the 4 wheel velocities I am using Ros2 Control.

[image: Simple swerve drive robot model in RViz]

I created a [simple test model](https://youtu.be/fR47Y7p4mtQ) that drives the wheels in a pattern (so not actual coordinated steering). For this test I used the [joint_trajectory_controller](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/doc/userdoc.html) to control the steering angles and the [velocity controller](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/velocity_controllers/doc/userdoc.html) to control the wheel velocities.

The ROS packages for this test were:

- The [description package](https://github.com/pvandervelde/zinger_description/tree/066679dd8d047fc9f32d820e62bdf874d72209fe)
- The [package with the gazebo configuration](https://github.com/pvandervelde/zinger_ignition/tree/d5b7544aa0ff4454b5264d9a43bca55acc191f90)
- The [package with the test controllers](https://github.com/pvandervelde/zinger_controller_test_nodes/tree/171a680d311cc70e418f221d09623e1c82a2772c)

My next step is to enable coordinated steering. For that I need to be able to control the steering angles and the wheel velocities as well as the rate of change over time for both variables. This means that the velocity controller won't work because upon a change it will generate an instantaneous change velocity in Gazebo. This is a) not very realistic and b) means that the kinematics will be incorrect.

My approach was to use the JointTrajectoryController which allows providing a trajectory. This works for the control of the steering angles, but there are issues:

- The documentation indicates that you can send [JointTrajectory](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/trajectory_msgs/msg/JointTrajectory.html) messages with only velocity but that doesn't seem to be [implemented](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/issues/171)
- The documentation also indicates that you can send `JointTrajectory` messages with only accelerations (or velocity and acceleration) but Gazebo [doesn't implement the `acceleration`](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/2dbcc6c872a204e44f4dd3e3be8c44a98b04452f/src/systems/joint_traj_control/JointTrajectoryController.hh#L47) command or state interfaces. This leads to the command controller crashing if `acceleration` is specified as a command or state interface.

So the question is now: What is the best way to create a 4 wheel independent steering robot in ROS2 Humble + Gazebo Fortress. Would I need to implement my own ROS2 control controller? Or is there a better way. None of the available controllers seem applicable for my case.

Additionally how do I connect to Gazebo so that I can test my robot?

Comment: I was searching for same thing, but I found only this project https://github.com/MarkNaeem/ros_controllers (ROS1) Do you have any progress?

Comment: @injae At the moment I'm just using the position controller for the steering angle and the velocity controller for the wheel velocity. My code then interpolates between the current state and the desired state over 100 steps or something. It's not perfect but it does work. Code is here: https://github.com/pvandervelde/zinger_swerve_controller/blob/a1a47a2afa396d44030ca1e899937049a0b5e277/zinger_swerve_controller/swerve_controller.py#L405. At some point I'll create an actual ROS2 controller for swerve.